# VS 2010 Evaluate a debug expression into a reference I can use

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging

There's a specific value in a third party tool I want to change, after debugging I reached the value I want to change

This is the expression :

```
((De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.DataPoint)(((System.Delegate)((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<BlastFurnance.ChartObject>(((System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl)(chartSeries)).ItemsSource)).Items[0].PropertyChanged)).Target)).SelectedBrush
```

The main problem is : `System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView` doesn't exist, this why I can't handle it in my code.

I'm using WPF with modern UI metro charts from here:

https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/documentation

This the XAML code :

```
<my:StackedColumnChart Style="{StaticResource ChartxStyleFixedSize}"
                       ChartTitle="Stacked Column Chart with 2 fixed series"
                       ChartSubTitle="Chart with fixed width and height" 
                       Palette="{StaticResource Gradients}"
                       FontSize="{Binding Path=SelectedFontSize}"
                       IsRowColumnSwitched="{Binding Path=IsRowColumnSwitched}"
                       ToolTipFormat="{Binding Path=ToolTipFormat}"
                       Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground}" 
                       Background="{Binding Path=Background}" 
                       x:Name="StacksChart"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <my:StackedColumnChart.Series>
        <my:ChartSeries SeriesTitle="Funrnace"
                        DisplayMember="Category"
                        ValueMember="Number"
                        x:Name="chartSeries"                    
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=stacked}" />
    </my:StackedColumnChart.Series>
</my:StackedColumnChart>
```

This is the code that I'm debugging

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChartSeries x = chartSeries;
}
```

Like you see I'm debugging "x" in order to find the value of the brush as above.

thanks

Comment: has the stackedcolumnchart not a proeprty for SelectedBrush ?

Comment: I assume you need the ItemBrush property in DataPoint class. https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ModernUIChart/De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart/Core/DataPoint.cs

Comment: May be it's a dependency property. You can download source code and debug it.

Comment: @Der_Meister what do u mean by  dependency property ? 

i just want to reach it from chartseries object

Comment: If you want the SelectedBrush from the StackedColumnChart why don't you then get it from it? in your code: StacksChart.SelectedBrush. Or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you're looking for:

```
StacksChart.DataPointGroups[0].DataPoints[0].SelectedBrush
```

However, you can use common property for the entire chart as Mark said.

```
StacksChart.SelectedBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Comment: I made a search in the library sources. I found that DataPoint has such property and data points are added to data point groups.

Comment: StacksChart.DataPointGroups[0].DataPoints[0].ItemBrush , for my problem it would be using ItemBrush instead of SelectedBrush , thanks !

Comment: I made the same search , but didn't link them ! thanks